# Flutter Provider Navigator Not Found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

So I'm getting this error and I've tried everything that other StackOverflow threads recommend but no luck.

```
E/flutter ( 1461): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
E/flutter ( 1461): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
E/flutter ( 1461): #0      Navigator.of.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2553
E/flutter ( 1461): #1      Navigator.of
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2560
E/flutter ( 1461): #2      Navigator.pushNamed
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:1621
E/flutter ( 1461): #3      LockState.unlockWithLocalAuth
package:journal/provider/LockState.dart:47
E/flutter ( 1461): #4      LockState.didChangeAppLifecycleState
package:journal/provider/LockState.dart:33
E/flutter ( 1461): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is my MaterialApp:

```
return MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
    supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
    locale: context.locale,
    builder: (context, child) {
      return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<LockState>(
                create: (_) => LockState(context)),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<FileUploadState>(
                create: (_) => FileUploadState(
                    Provider.of<UserState>(context).firebaseUser.uid)),
          ],
          child: ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: RemoveScrollGlow(),
            child: child,
          ));
    },
    initialRoute:
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? '/sign-in' : '/home',
    routes: {
      '/sign-in': (context) {
        return SignInScreen(
          actions: [
            AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
              Phoenix.rebirth(context);
            }),
          ],
          providerConfigs: providerConfigs,
        );
      },
      '/home': (context) => JournalsScreen(),
      '/settings': (context) => SettingsScreen(),
      '/lock': (context) => LockScreen(),
      '/premium': (context) => PremiumScreen(),
      '/journalDetails': (context) => JournalDetailsScreen(),
      '/writeJournalEntry': (context) => WriteJournalScreen()
    });
```

In my LockState, I am overriding didChangeAppLifecycleState and run

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(_context, "/lock");
```

from there and then the exception is thrown. Lots of stuff going on with context here so I assumed I just have it set up wrong somewhere in here.

And here is how I'm passing the context into the LockState. Maybe this is invalid when I use it?

```
   BuildContext _context;
  bool _isLockScreenOpen = false;

  LockState(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
    _localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.resumed);
  }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the **MaterialApp** inside the **MultiProvider**, as opposed to creating the **MultiProvider** in the **MaterialApp**'s builder method; basically your main method should look like this:

```dart
void main() {
  
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [ //... your providers ],
      child: MaterialApp( 
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          initialRoute: '',
          routes: { //... your routes
        )
      )
   );
```

Try this and see.

Comment: I tried this, and just tried this again. Same error.

Comment: I just added more details about how I'm passing the context to LockState. Maybe that will help?

Comment: I still think you should make the **MaterialApp** the root widget, wrapped inside the **MultiProvider**, since the error clearly says "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator". Whenever you're calling **Navigator.of(context)**, you cannot go up the widget tree and fetch a Navigator because of the way you have your app structured. You're using a context that's above MaterialApp to fetch the navigator. I see you're passing a context to the MaterialApp and its dependencies that doesn't come from it.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure what to do then even with the MultiProvider above the MaterialApp.

Comment: In the above code, when you say **return MaterialApp**, can you show me what the parent widget to that is (the enclosing widget)? that's the source of your issues. That enclosing widget is not providing an instance of Navigator to its children widgets (from the MaterialApp and down).

Comment: It's just a stateless App widget with a build method. There is no Navigator above the widget.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue identically how you have it. The issue is like I mentioned above, your stateless App widget does not have a parent that contains the Navigator that any child can access via inheritance, so that context you're injecting into your services in the **MultiProvider** is the issue.  You're gonna have to inject them whenever you need the context inside those services. In whichever class you need to invoke the context, pass it in from the child class you're invoking it. I can send you a Gist if you want, but that's your most viable option.

Comment: That definitely helps! I tried calling unlockWithLocalAuth(BuildContext context) from child widgets and it did fine. The problem is that I want to run unlockWithLocalAuth inside didChangeAppLifecycle(), which I can't pass in the context. I may have to take that out of LockState and refactor some things.